# jQuery selector not working properly with drop up menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made an drop up menu but it is not working properly. See fiddle or the code: https://jsfiddle.net/9u6fc7wp/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $(".links>li>a:not(.sub-menu a)").mouseenter(function() {
      $(".sub-menu-bg").addClass("menu-bg-up");

      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".sub-menu").fadeIn();
      }, 700);
    });
    $(".sub-menu-bg").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".sub-menu").fadeOut();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".sub-menu-bg").removeClass("menu-bg-up");
      }, 500);
    });
  }());
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
}
footer {
  background: white;
  color: #8a8a8a;
  font-family: TWcenMTregular;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1vh 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9100;
  width: 100%;
}
footer .links {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
footer .links>li {
  float: left;
  width: 24%;
  position: relative;
}
footer .links li::after {
  content: ' | ';
  float: right;
}
footer .links li:last-child::after {
  content: '';
}
footer .links li a {
  color: #8a8a8a;
}
footer .links li:hover > a {
  color: #9ebe2d;
}
footer .links li:hover .sub-menu li:first-child a {
  color: #9ebe2d;
}
footer .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: initial;
  padding: 0px 0;
  margin: 0!important;
  font-family: TWcenMTregular;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  display: none;
}
footer .sub-menu li {
  text-align: center;
}
footer .sub-menu li:first-child {
  font-family: prismRegular;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
footer .sub-menu li::after {
  content: '';
  margin: 0;
}
footer .sub-menu li a {
  color: #8a8a8a;
}
footer .sub-menu li a:hover {
  color: #9ebe2d;
}
footer .sub-menu-bg {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: initial;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  height: 0;
}
.menu-bg-up {
  height: 165px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#">link1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sub-menu-bg"></div>
</footer>
```

If you move the mouse slowly, it works fine. I used timeout function which makes the sub menu links appear later. If you move the cursor to one of the links and immediately move to the empty place where the links will appear. When the cursor makes contact with the links, the drop up menu dissapears.. It must only disappear when the cursor leaves the footer. To me it seems that the selectors are not working properly while that should fix the problem. I only want mouseenter on the first a children of the `.links>li`

If this can be done with only CSS please show me how. I have done all i could. I hope I clearly explained the problem and feel free to ask questions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in CSS. I gave an example below;

https://jsfiddle.net/9u6fc7wp/1/

```css
.links {
  position: relative;
  width: 24%;
}
.links > a::after {
  content: "|";
  float: right;
}
.sub-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* hides sub-menu */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -172px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(2em);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}
.links:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  /* shows sub-menu */
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
  /* this removes the transition delay so the menu will be visible while the other styles transition */
}
/* presentational */

body {
  padding: 2%;
  font: 18px/1.4 sans-serif;
}
footer {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
footer a {
  color: #8a8a8a;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer a:hover {
  color: #9ebe2d;
}
footer ul,
footer ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
footer > ul {
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
footer > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
footer > ul > li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.sub-menu {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li class="links"><a href="#">link1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="links"><a href="#">link2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="links"><a href="#">link3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="links"><a href="#">link4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sub-menu-bg"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the reaction.. the example works fine and looks good but i dont see the background and the animations aren't the same.